# Calling the constructor of a base class inside the constructor of its derived class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to write a program that inserts different types of cakes into an invoice, and it uses several derived classes. I'd like to use the constructor of a derived class to also initialize some data members in the abstract parent class. Is there a way I can do this so I can keep the data members private and, inside the derived class, call the base class constructor to initialize them? Ex:

```
class Cake: 
public:
    Cake(string flavor, string frosting) {
        cakeType = flavor;
        frostingType = frosting;
    }
private:
    string cakeType;
    string frostingType;
};

class LayerCake: public Cake {
public: 
    LayerCake(string flavor, string frosting, int layers, int 
    quantity) {
        numLayers = layers;
        cakeQuantity = quantity;
        Cake(flavor, frosting);
private:
    int numLayers;
    int cakeQuantity;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the constructor's body, `Cake(flavor, frosting);` just constructs a temporary `Cake`, which has nothing to do with the base class subobject of the derived class.

What you want is [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), e.g.

```
class LayerCake: public Cake {
public: 
    LayerCake(string flavor, string frosting, int layers, int 
    quantity) : Cake(flavor, frosting) {
//            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        numLayers = layers;
        cakeQuantity = quantity;
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: If I'm using a header file, do I use this syntax in both the declaration and implementation, or just the implementation?

Comment: @Jake Just the implementation.